# Implementing guided navigation using vespa

Tags: vespa

I'm trying to implement guided navigation using vespa. At present, I am using grouping to implement it. I've written a query like this.

`SELECT * FROM entity where sddocname contains 'entity' | all(group(category) each(group(item_category) each(output(count()))));`

In the above example category is like "electronics","automobiles" etc and "item_category" is like "mobile phone","car"etc.

I don't want to select any documents, I just wanted to see the grouped data. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use limit 0 to remove the plain hit list. Example here https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/tutorials/blog-search.html

limit 0 in yql or just specify &hits=0

Comment: My intention was to implement guided navigation. I happened to bump into a feature called parent/child relationship concept in vespa. Is it better to use it rather than grouping?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by guided navigation but to me guided navigation is about run time aggregation over dynamic data which changes with the query formulation.